# Using built in 'edit' and 'delete' buttons in gridview. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I have a workout database where some data from most of the tables is pulled and outputted to a gridview.  I have taken a screenshot of my gridview output for reference.

http://postimage.org/image/vncyu4oet/

As you see I have the 'edit' and 'delete' buttons on the table.  There are two main things that I want to know how to do, and I have probed all over the web and haven't been able to find a solution.

1) When I click 'edit' I want only one row to be affected (which I have working), and I also want only certain cells to have the ability to be edited (namely the Date, Workout Name, Weight, and Repetitions), while the other ones can't be.  Is there a way to restrict that?  Lastly, once the user inputs data, how do I then update the multiple tables all at once? I have seen code on how to edit just one table, but my gridview pulls data from multiple tables like I said.

2) When clicking 'delete' I just want that row to be affected, not all the other rows that have a matching date, matching workout name, etc.

Any help is appreciated!!